# Table of results is not closing from above

Tags: tables

The problem is that the table is not closing from above. Secondary problem (which I don't really care) is that a vertical line is replicated.

Here is the code:

```
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
$\displaystyle
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l||l|l|l|}
\multicolumn{8}{|c|}{CGAL statistics} \\
\hline
tree & N & dim & nodes & depth & brute & cgal & speedup \\
\hline
\multirow{1}{*}{5e-06} & 150 & 20 & 69 & 9 & 0.000008 & 0.00006 & 0.14\\
\hline
\multirow{1}{*}{1.1e-05} & 150 & 30 & 68 & 9 & 0.00001 & 0.00006 & 0.16\\
\hline
\multirow{1}{*}{1.2e-05} & 150 & 50 & 68 & 9 & 0.00001 & 0.00008 & 0.13\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
$}
```

Outcome:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You're `tabular` environment is missing an `\hline` instruction immediately after `\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l||l|l|l|}`.

Comment: Add an `\hline` command at  the beginning of the table. But you  can as well let it open, if you suppress the vertical lines in the first row.

Comment: `$\displaystyle` and the trailing `$` are useless; add `%` after the open brace `\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%` and after `\end{tabular}` (or put the closing brace just after it). Are you sure you need to resize the table?

Comment: Thanks for the welcoming! :) You were right about `\hline`. You could answer the question so that I can accept this as an answer. @egreg not really, but it seems nice as it is. I did the `%` thing you said, but I just noticed a small difference in the size. However, the problem is solved now! :)

Comment: It's never a good idea to do `\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{..` it just generates inconsistent font sizes through the document, just choose a suitable font size such as `\small` and stick to it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think I did that because the table was too small! I suspect that you mean `\Large{..}`, where in the dots I can put the code for the table.

Comment: @G.Samaras well yes whatever size (preferably no size change at all) but the syntax is `{\large ..}` not `\large{..}` size changes do not take an argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you need an `\hline` instruction to tell LaTeX to draw a full-width horizontal line.

Rather than create a table with lots and lots of vertical lines and quite a few horizontal lines, consider setting up a table with *no* vertical lines and just a few, but well-spaced horizontal lines. For that, use the macros `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `bottomrule` of the `booktabs` package. Next, since some of the columns could benefit from extra formatting, consider loading the `siunitx` package and its `S` column type. And, if you want the table to span the full width of the text block, consider using a `tabular*` environment instead of resizing the `tabular` using `\resizebox` and getting a noticeably larger font size for the material inside the table. Finally, since the `\multirow` directives don't do anything, you should omit them entirely. The result of these suggestions is shown below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs} % new
\sisetup{group-digits=false,tight-spacing=true} % new
\begin{document}
original form (with \verb+\hline+ added):

\bigskip\noindent
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l||l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{8}{|c|}{CGAL statistics} \\
\hline
tree & N & dim & nodes & depth & brute & cgal & speedup \\
\hline
\multirow{1}{*}{5e-06} & 150 & 20 & 69 & 9 & 0.000008 & 0.00006 & 0.14\\
\hline
\multirow{1}{*}{1.1e-05} & 150 & 30 & 68 & 9 & 0.00001 & 0.00006 & 0.16\\
\hline
\multirow{1}{*}{1.2e-05} & 150 & 50 & 68 & 9 & 0.00001 & 0.00008 & 0.13\\
\hline
\end{tabular}}

\bigskip\bigskip
suggested alternative form:

\medskip
\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
   S[table-format=1.1e2] 
   cccc 
   S[table-format=1.6] 
   S[table-format=1.5] 
   c @{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{8}{c}{CGAL statistics} \\
{tree} & N & dim & nodes & depth & {brute} & {cgal} & speedup \\
\midrule
5e-06 & 150 & 20 & 69 & 9 & 0.000008 & 0.00006 & 0.14\\
1.1e-05 & 150 & 30 & 68 & 9 & 0.00001 & 0.00006 & 0.16\\
1.2e-05 & 150 & 50 & 68 & 9 & 0.00001 & 0.00008 & 0.13\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{document}
```